# how to select last two records ordered by date DESC and grouping by field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a problem that is driving me crazy and I hope that someone of you can help me.

I have a table where I store some videos from youtube. Now, for each channel I store via youtube API 20 videos. So if I have 6 channel I'll have 120 videos. Every video has a kind of "timestamp".
I need to extract from this table the last two videos ordered DESC by publishedAt field for each channel. I tried as uploaded screenshot but it's not what I want.

Someone could help me please?
Sql: version 5.5.60-MariaDB-Mysql
Thank you for any help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq2Hh.png)

This is what I tried for a long time

```
          SELECT publishedAt, channelId, channeltitle
          FROM video_from_youtube a
          WHERE a.id
            IN (
              SELECT MAX(t.id)
              FROM video_from_youtube t
              WHERE a.channelId = t.channelId
             )
            OR
                a.id
            IN (
              SELECT MAX(t.id)
              FROM video_from_youtube t
              WHERE a.channelId = t.channelId AND 
              t.id NOT IN (
                  SELECT MAX(t2.id)
                  FROM video_from_youtube t2
                  WHERE t.channelId = t2.channelId
                )
             )       
          ORDER BY a.publishedAt DESC, a.id[enter image description here][1]
```

[this is the actually query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HNEJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query. The subquery v is to order the data by channel and timestamp. The subquery o is to assign a number for each video in each channel. Session variables are required here.  When the channel changes (@channel_id is the channel of previous row), the number starts from 1.

```
SELECT o.publishedAt, o.channelId, o.channeltitle
FROM (
  SELECT v.*,
        (@video_order := CASE WHEN @channel_id = v.channelId THEN @video_order + 1 ELSE 1 END ) as row_num,
        (@channel_id := v.channelId) AS channel_id
  FROM (
    SELECT t.publishedAt, t.channelId, t.channeltitle
    FROM video_from_youtube t
    ORDER BY t.channelId, t.publishedAt DESC) v 
  ) o
WHERE o.row_num<=2;
```

Comment: If you use mysql 8, it will be much easier using CTE

Comment: Thank you for supporting me. I've tried your query and the results is: "Error SQL (1064): You have an error in you SQL syntax; check the manual that corrisponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (
    SELECT t.publishedAt, t.channelId, t.channeltitle
    FROM video_fr' at line 6..

I never used "Session variables"... and honestly I don't know what kind or error is.. I'm looking on docs to find out something more

Comment: There is an extra comma. I just removed it. Please try it again

Comment: The query give me another error :(

#1054 - Unknown column 't.channelId' in 'field list'
It doesn't recognize 't.channelId' in the second select

Comment: fixed. SOrry I can't test it. Try it again

Comment: No worries PeterHe and thank you for helping me. Now the query works fine. Just the result, it extract the last 4 rows ordered desc instead 2... what should I have to edit in the query?

Comment: Not sure what's going on. Can you post the table structure, some sample data, and expected results?

Comment: Sure! the structure table -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq2Hh.png
Your result query -> http://www.vcerruti.com/3.png

thank you so much for the time you are dedicating me

Comment: Can you add o.row_num to the select list so we can see the real row num for each channel

Comment: adding o.row_num the query works exactley as I expected. Thank you very much for your suport @PeterHe. I really appreciate a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more simply:

```
SELECT vfy.publishedAt, vfy.channelId, vfy.channeltitle
FROM video_from_youtube vfy
WHERE vfy.id >= (SELECT vfy2.id
                 FROM video_from_youtube vfy
                 WHERE vfy2.channelId = vfy.channelId
                 ORDER BY vfy2.id DESC
                 LIMIT 1, 1  -- get the second
                )
ORDER BY publishedAt DESC;
```

Comment: thank you for trying but my mysql version I'm using not allow me to use LIMIT in subquery. It returns "Error SQL (1235): This versione of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"

Comment: @overRide . . . Try removing the `ANY`.

Comment: Lindoff the query you wrote works fine and extract 2 rows for channelId but they are not the last ordered desc.. what should I need to edit in the query? Thank you